# How to define a function with "this" context in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

```
type Animal = {
    name: string
}

function getBear(this: Animal) : Animal {
    this.name = "hi"
    return this
}

console.log(getBear().name)
```

Could any one help me with this , i am not able to call the getBear function

Comment: You explicitly define that `this` has to be `Animal`, but you call `getBear` on no object so it is `void`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this because the `this` context of `getBear` is not bound to an `Animal` when you call it. Simply telling TypeScript that `this` is an `Animal` isn't enough, you also have to call your function with that context.

In this case you would need to call it like this.

```
type Animal = {
    name: string
}

function getBear(this: Animal) : Animal {
    this.name = "hi"
    return this
}

console.log(getBear.call({ name: "test" }).name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call this 3 ways:

```
type Animal = {
    name: string
}

function getBear(this: Animal, a: string): Animal {
    this.name = a
    return this
}

// First one 

// function.call(objcontext,parameters) calls a function under a different object context.
// read more at : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

console.log(getBear.call({ name: "test" }, "Username").name)

// Here we create a object 
//second
console.log(new (getBear as any)("Username").name)

//third
console.log(new (<any>getBear)("Praveen").name)
```